# LESS Nested Selector isn't Working

Tags: css, less

relatively new to LESS so this might be something I'm doing wrong...

Currently using LESS to create stylesheets and preprocessing to CSS using Grunt and the grunt-contrib-less plugin.

Hitting a bit of a brick wall here though.

My LESS selector is:

```
h1{
    .navbar-brand {
    font-family: @bodyfont;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0px;
    }
}
```

But it's being processed to:

```
h1 .navbar-brand {
font-family: 'Museo';
display: inline;
margin: 0px;
}
```

Note the space between the tag and the class, this is causing it not to work.

Am I misunderstanding something about the nested selector or is something awry with the Grunt processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
h1{
    &.navbar-brand {
    font-family: @bodyfont;
    display: inline;
    margin: 0px;
    }
}
```

should do what you want, assuming you want the final output to be `h1.navbar-brand`.

The `&` is the "self" selector. I use it often with `:hover`, like

```
a {
  ..
  &:hover {
    ..
  }
}
```

Comment: That is absolutely perfect, I'll make sure to read the docs a bit more on this... thanks very much!